# How do I access a structure member with a pointer in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am practicing with linklist in `C`. My objective is that I want to delete a node using a function outside of main.
My plan to accomplish this objective is to access the next pointer without clearing/deleting/freeing the head pointer, but I get an error:

> "[Error] request for member 'nextptr' in something not a structure or union"

The code:

```
void del(struct node **head) {
    struct node *temp = *head;
    //this is what I believe is wrong, i need to access nextptr of head
    *head->nextptr = temp->nextptr->nextptr;
    free(temp->nextptr);
    temp->nextptr = NULL;
```

Comment: Perhaps `(*head)->nextptr`?

Comment: It fixes it, but why though?

Comment: @DasFalscheGewinn because of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). BTW: `temp->nextptr->nextptr;` looks fishy, if `temp->nextptr` is `NULL` you'll be in trouble

Answer (score 1):

Postfix operators like `->` have higher precedence than unary `*`, so `*head->nextptr` is parsed as `*(head->nextptr)` - you're trying to apply the `->` operator to `head` (not `*head`), which is a pointer *to a pointer* to a `struct` type, hence the error.

To fix it, you need to explicitly dereference `head` before applying the `->` operator, so you need to write it as `(*head)->nextptr`.